# Jtextpane doesn't scroll down enough

Tags: java, swing, htmleditorkit

I'm writing a chat application in which it's possible to post images (using html.) The messages are shown in a Jtextpane, wrapped in a Jscrollpane, which is set to scroll down each time a message is received. For normal text, this works quite well, however, images need to reload every time a message is received, and the scrollpane seems to scroll down -before- the images have finished loading, leaving it only partially scrolled down. I tried constantly scrolling it down from another thread, but this doesn't seem to do it, so I'm guessing it doesn't see the image object's real size, only the small "placeholder" pic that's loaded before the actual image?

```
public void addMessage(String sender, String msg) throws BadLocationException, IOException{

    pane.setEditorKit(kit);
    pane.setDocument(doc);

    kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<b>[" + sender + "]</b> " + msg, 0, 0, null);
    pane.setCaretPosition(pane.getDocument().getLength());
}
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Delegate the image display to a `SwingWorker` or similar, and then scroll once the Worker completes (and the image is present / accessible). Failing that, overload `addMessage` to account for images being passed and pass in the image dimensions at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

> so I'm guessing it doesn't see the image object's real size, only the small "placeholder" pic that's loaded before the actual image?

```
pane.setCaretPosition(pane.getDocument().getLength());
```

Try wrapping that code in a `SwingUtilties.invokeLater()` so the code get added to the end of the EDT. Hopefully the Document will be then properly updated when the code executes.

I would also consider using regular text with styled attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32235020/131872. I find it easier to work with attributes then to worry about proper formatting of the text string with HTML.